# No map marker info on click event

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an Android app that shows map markers on an Google Map.

I want to show some info from every marker when the user clicks on it.
Now, the markers are shown, but nothing happens when the user clicks on the marker.

Here is my code:

```
   @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


        mGoogleMap.clear();
        getMarkers();
        //move map camera
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,14));

    }
    private void getMarkers() {
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("Response: ", response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String getObject = jObj.getString("wisata");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);
                        latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));
                        tipo = jsonObject.getString(TIPO);
                        Log.d("Response","Tipo ="+tipo);

                        // Menambah data marker untuk di tampilkan ke google map
                        addMarker(latLng, title,tipo);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
    }
    private void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title, final String tipo_reporte) {

        markerOptions.position(latlng);

        if (tipo_reporte.equals("1")) {
            Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.reten1);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();

            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true));
            Bitmap icono = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icono));
            markerOptions.snippet(title);
        }


        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

What should I change to get marker info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
setOnInfoWindowClickListener(...)
```

with

```
setOnMarkerClickListener(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use markers with `onClickListener`.